# Wordpress Contact Form 7 Additional Settings condition based on dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, plugins, customization

I am looking to add a condition on the Contact Form 7 Additional Settings but really struggling because I am not sure what is supported and not.

Basically I want to do a basic validation based on the drop-down value in order to send user to to different "location.replace" because the cost will be different between U7 and U8.

```
if the user selected U7 from dropdown
{
    location.replace('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=XXXXX');
}
else if user selected U8
{
    location.replace('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=YYYYY');
}
else
{
    do nothing
}
```

Please help and thank you so much in advance.